# What's my entitlement if prize not received

Tags: contract-law, civil-law

Let's say I pay money to enter a raffle (assuming raffle is legal as I understand it may not be legal in all states) and win the raffle.

The prize is either an item of value or the value of the item if the item is no longer available.

Now if the raffle holder decides not to award either prize, am entitled to the prize/value of prize or a refund of purchase price of ticket or nothing at all?

I know there would be several things to factor in, but is there any kind of example that would give me an idea how a court would view a lawsuit of this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a raffle is typically a game of chance, it's not highly likely that it is legal, though it is possible. In Washington, some charitable organizations can hold a raffle, if they follow a bunch of rules – it depends on the state. Assuming that the raffle is legal, the right to a prize falls within contract law ([Thao v. Contral Data](http://courts.mrsc.org/appellate/057wnapp/057wnapp0802.htm), [Coleman v. Lottery Bureau](http://www.leagle.com/decision/197742677MichApp349_1382/COLEMAN%20v.%20LOTTERY%20BUREAU)). It is possible that the terms of the contest were not satisfied – that was an issue in some real estate raffles, that there had to be some minimum number of sales. If the minimum sales figure is not met, then the raffle would be canceled and tickets would be refunded. Other reasons to cancel a raffle include being told by the state that you have to (they decide it's illegal). Another possibility is that the customer is mistaken about what was being raffled off. Unless there is something in the terms that clearly indicates that the 'customer' is simply making a donation and this really isn't a raffle, then you have an offer, acceptance, consideration and mutuality, i.e. a contract. The rafflers could them be legally obligated to award the prize (or equivalent). So the main questions would be: is it legal, is it just a donation, was there an actual winner. I don't see any way that they could legally just keep the money.

Comment: Ok, would it then be up to a court of law to determine what is owed?  Or would the prize (or equivalent) be awarded as judgement?  Assuming this is a legal raffle (contract), no donation in the terms, etc.